# How to configure custom notification message in backoffice wizard

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, wizard, backoffice

Please guys, could you advise how I can configure a custom message to display on creation error of some particular object (for example, B2BCustomer)

[image: I want to customize text at this pop up]

I tried to do it this way:

[image: Xml configuration that I added to backoffice-config.xml]

But it just changed this message at all occurrences of such error. With this XML code, my custom message is shown everywhere on object creation fail, but I need to show my custom message only when B2BCustomer creation fails.

Who can help me, please??

Answer (score -2):

look through this link in the documentation: https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/6.7.0.0/en-US/8bc9570b86691014a901c290d2c5f107.html

implement this interface:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ustp.png)

- in toString() return your message that should be displayed on exception.
- in canHandle() method write a condition when this message should be shown.

(When you implement this interface all exceptions are passed through your canHandle() method, so the condition set in this method should be very precise to return true only for your specific case)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.